# How to get resultant statevector after applying parameterized gates in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state

I want to check the expressibility of my ansatz and calculate the resultant statevector on paper seems difficult. Is there a way I can do this in qiskit? I have the circuit for the ansatz which has parameterized controlled $Y$-axis rotations. Is there a way I can get the resultant statevector in terms of my parameters $\theta$?

I am also working with efficient $SU(2)$ ansatz. Is there any resource on this? Anything that covers the expressibility and efficiency of this kind of ansatz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get the resultant statevector in temrs of my parameter $\theta$s?

I don't think Qiskit itself has this functionality. May be this is because symbolic expressions become nasty very quickly when circuit size increases.

There is, however, a package developed by [@SimoneGasperini](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/22702/simonegasperini) named [qiskit-symb](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb) which can be used to achieve this.

To demonstrate how to use this package, let's create a sample parameterized circuit:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
circ = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=4, reps=1)
circ = circ.decompose()
```

We get the `Statevector` as follows:

```
from qiskit_symb.quantum_info import Statevector
state_vec = Statevector(circ)
state_vec.to_sympy()
```

And to assign the parameters:

```
sv_func = state_vec.to_lambda()

params = [0.12, 0.34, 0.56, 0.78]
psi = sv_func(*params)

psi
```

Comment: It's a shame that it's not doable in plain Qiskit. Do you know if there's been a discussion about it on Qiskit's GitHub? Otherwise, it would be worth a try to submit the idea there

Comment: [@Tristan Nemoz](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/10454/tristan-nemoz), here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4751

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using this package and update here later

Comment: @CheshtaJoshi feel free to contact me if you need any support to use my [qiskit-symb](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb) package

Comment: This is amazing @SimoneGasperini . It works perfectly well!